# Checking for an uninitalised int when an actual value could be 0?

Tags: java, android, initialization, int

I have some code where I have an int that starts off uninitialised, and is set later in the code (post user action).

If the values haven't been initialised, then I use default values for display. I check if the values are 0 to tell if they've been initialised or not.

The issue arises when the user chooses the 0 value. If the 0 value is chosen, then the check for initialisation fails and the default value is used.

How would I check for intialiasation? I have a feeling I would have to use the `Integer` class and check for a null value. Is this the only way?

Comment: use Integer and check for null, yes. Another option is to use an  Optional (see guava for an implementation)

Answer (score 2):

Are there any other `int` values to signify "not initialized"? For example, -1.

If all values of `int` are possible, then you need some external mechanism. `Integer` as `null` works, as well as e.g. a `boolean` storing initialization status.

Comment: Didn't think of that. 0 is the smallest value.

Answer (score 1):

As your suggested yourself, use of `Integer` for a check against `null` is appropriate here. The only other way that comes to my mind would be declaring a flag (e.g. like `boolean isUserValue = false`) that remains false until the user  chooses a value.